# Separate or Split Respone from PHP to AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

> This is my PHP Code contains an array of tokens

```
$date=$_POST['date'];

$query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT tokenno from at_booking where date='$date' and status='Booked'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

    echo json_encode($row);

}
```

> This is my ajax respone code

```
date_input.change(function () {
        $("#tokens").show();
        var data=$("#date").val();
        //alert("data"+data);
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'tokens.php',
            data : {date: data},

            success:function(response){
                alert("response= "+response);
            }
        });

    });
```

> Iam getting response like this

```
response= {"0":"Token1","tokenno":"Token1"}{"0":"Token2","tokenno":"Token2"}{"0":"Token3","tokenno":"Token3"}{"0":"Token4","tokenno":"Token4"}{"0":"Token5","tokenno":"Token5"}{"0":"Token6","tokenno":"Token6"}{"0":"Token8","tokenno":"Token8"}{"0":"Token7","tokenno":"Token7"}{"0":"Token9","tokenno":"Token9"}{"0":"Token10","tokenno":"Token10"}
```

> I bit confused how to split the response and i have to get output "Token1" from {"0":"Token1","tokenno":"Token1"} and "Token2" from {"0":"Token2","tokenno":"Token2"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can push in array and then return it as json

```
$date=$_POST['date'];

$query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT tokenno from at_booking where date='$date' and status='Booked'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

    $arr[] = $row;

}

    echo json_encode($arr);
```

in JS code try this

```
 var values = [];
date_input.change(function () {
        $("#tokens").show();
        var data=$("#date").val();
        //alert("data"+data);
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'tokens.php',
            data : {date: data},

            success:function(response){
                $.each(data,function(key,value){
                    values.push(value.tokenno);
                });

                console.log(values);


            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: iam getting response like this response= [{"0":"Token1","tokenno":"Token1"},{"0":"Token2","tokenno":"Token2"},{"0":"Token3","tokenno":"Token3"},{"0":"Token4","tokenno":"Token4"},{"0":"Token5","tokenno":"Token5"},{"0":"Token6","tokenno":"Token6"},{"0":"Token8","tokenno":"Token8"},{"0":"Token7","tokenno":"Token7"},{"0":"Token9","tokenno":"Token9"},{"0":"Token10","tokenno":"Token10"}].how to split the response and i have to get only token1 token2

Comment: yes you got an array of object is you use $.each you can split the result  see my edit

Comment: could you tell me pls how to split the result

Comment: split is converting string to Array and response here is an array please use my javascript code and if you want an advanced exemple i will give it to you

Comment: Please give that example dude

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/1tgLqkhn/ and i EDITED My Answer . if help please set my anwser as accepted anwser

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something more like this, and then go over the data with jquery .each()

```
$date=$_POST['date'];

$query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT tokenno from at_booking where date='$date' and status='Booked'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

$rows[]=$row;

}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($rows);
```